# ASP Broken Image, Correct Url

Tags: asp.net, image, url

I am creating a web application. I have a page that displays a series of images. To do this, I use code like the following, which only changes the url between images:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image4" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Content/Images/logo.png" AlternateText="Logo">
```

If I open the design view, Visual Studio 2010 shows me the images correctly. However when launching the application, all the images on the page do not appear. An icon appears instead, as if the image can not be found or has been damaged.

Although, if I right-click on one of the images and select "Open Image in New Tab" the image opens perfectly. If I use the option of Google Chrome "inspect element", and I click on the url of the image, it opens without any problem.

But the page does not load any images when I open it

Does anyone know why this is happening? Why opening the page does not show any images, despite the url being correct, I can follow it and open the image?

EDIT:

I have uploaded 2 images to imgur.

In this you can see that image fails to load and I get an error 404: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LJNs.png

In this you can see that when i click on "Open Image on new tab", the image is open correctly: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWRn3.png

EDIT2:
I have noticed that it tries to charge the image from "/rwd-router/Content/" instead of "/Content". Why is it adding this folder?

Comment: how are you changing the image .. put that code too

Comment: I'm not changing the images. I mean the only diference between images are the url. All the images have the same code: <asp:Image ID="ImageX" runat="server" ImageUrl="different url" AlternateText="Logo">. Obviously the ID property is set to: image1, image2,...

Comment: Try putting _/_ at the beginning of your link instead of _~_

Comment: Perfect IgnasaK. It did the trick!!

Comment: Putting / at the beginning will force your images to always be at `/Content/Images/...` I would recommend that you keep `~/Content/Images/...` part if you can, since it makes your site more resilient when you decide to install your site to an IIS server...  Read [this](http://thesharad.wordpress.com/2010/09/29/what-does-the-character-%E2%80%98%E2%80%99-mean-in-asp-net-applications/) for more info...

Comment: I would prefer to keep it too. In other webpages there wasn't any problems. I don't know why this is happening only in this form. But the end line is coming, and i have to continue with the developing.

Answer (score 0):

When using Google Chrome, try out the **Network Panel** to confirm that your images loaded correctly...

A Get Status 200 - OK means the image loaded correctly...

[image: Network panel]

Comment: Using Chrome tools, I get error 404 for the images. It tries to load this link: "http://localhost:62741/rwd-router/Content/Images/logo.png" However if I open a new tab, and I open http://localhost:62741/Content/Images/logo.png" (without rwd-router, wich is written by him) the image is opened.

Comment: I have edited my question. I added 2 images where you can see the behaviour I described.

Comment: The `rwd-router` part is the name of your site's root... For some reason your web server can't find the images at "/rwd-router/Content/Images/logo.png"...